# invalid syntax elif python error

Tags: python

I'm getting an ELIF error on the elif myanswer == "1": line
It say's syntax error then points to the end of the elif.
Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it.

```
#if statements to make the first scenario run
print(place1)
while not gameOver:
    print(option1)
    myanswer = getanswer()
    elif myanswer == "1":
        print("nothing happens, the dog just waits")
    elif myanswer == "2":
        print("You nobely decide to fight the dog.")
#if statements to make the second scenario run
        print(place2)
        while not (belly and head and tail):
            print(option2)
            myanswer = getanswer(["1","2","3","4"])
            if myanswer == "1":
               print("You scratched the dog on the head with your claws")
               head = True
            elif myanswer == "2":
               print("You bite into the dog's soft belly")
               belly = True
            elif myanswer =="3":
               print("You cut off the dog's tail with your razor sharp teeth")
               tail = True
            elif myanswer =="4":
               print("You carefully retreat some steps away from the dog")
               print(situation1) #return to the main loop
               break # leave the dog loop                  
               break # leave the dog loop and leave main loop
        else:
            # dog loop was leaved correctly
            print("The dog bleeds from head, tail and belly and runs away."
                  "You are victorious! Congratulation, you have won the game")
            gameOver = True #leave the dog loop correctly 
    elif myanswer == "3":
        print("You run away, but the dog is faster than you and eats you whole!."
              "The dog eat you. Game Over")
        gameOver = True
print("Try again and thanks for playing")
```

Comment: change the first `elif` to `if`, because you can only have an `elif` is there is also an `if` statement. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Because it that `elif` has **no** trailing `if` condition, Either change it to `if` or add an `if`statement above it. Also You are using 2 `break` statements at the same indentation level and that wont work as expected.

Comment: you can only write elif after an if. the first one should be replaced by `if`

Comment: Being a puppy - I'm not sure I like the aggression towards the dog here :( :p

Answer (score 0):

`elif` can only be used after and `if` statement. replace your first `elif`

```
    elif myanswer == "1"
```

with

```
    if myanswer == "1":
```